# Shouldn't flags be dismissed if a question is closed?

Tags: bug, flags, on-hold

Yesterday I flagged https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17447740/how-to-exit-application-by-moving-mouse-or-any-key-press-over-axshockwaveflash-i with a close reason. When I looked at my flagging history, it was "on hold", but my flag was still open. I thought those flags were automatically deemed helpful if the question was closed.

> [image]

Comment: @Mołot 1. It's automatic, how would the software determine the right close reason, 2. even then the flag should be dismissed in some way

Comment: @Mołot Mods can't deal with each individual flag against a post, they deal with the flagged post itself and can either accept or decline the flags associated with it. What if a question got flagged 10 times by different users - mods shouldn't have to deal with each of those ones when it's the post itself that needs to be dealt with.

Comment: @JonW OK, there is truth in that.